# Comparing 2 Strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having some trouble with Haskell. I'm looking for a function that can compare 2 Strings. The function should output the a String with the characters that are in both Strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With or without repetitions? E.g., `f "aab" "aba" == "aab"` or `"ab"`?

Comment: What have you got so far? Where do you have a problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What are you looking for is some function that can intersect elements of 2 lists `[a]`.

There is one from [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html): `intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

```
> intersect "abcd" "db"
"bd"
it :: [Char]
```